# Migrating from Rational Apex Ada compiler to GCC Ada compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, ada

I will be working on a software development project using Ada language. Customer is using Rational Apex Ada compiler and I will be using GNU compiler. My code should work fine in customer's pc. What are all the possible compiler dependent code in Ada language? So that I can develope a compiler independent code. Also I want to compile and execute customer's code in my pc.

Thanks
Padmapriya

Comment: As the difficulty will hinge on the (unspecified) dependencies, your question is overly broad. Please don't hesitate to edit this question (or pose a new one) regarding specific problems you encounter.

Answer (score 4):

The next release of GNAT Pro will provide a new "pragma Profile (Rational)" to aid with porting from Apex to GNAT. See http://docs.adacore.com/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_rm_2.html#SEC110 for a description.

Comment: Hey, is this Britt Snodgrass? Welcome to StackOverflow! Free upvote for you!

Comment: Hi Marc. Yes, it's me. I've been lurking here occassionally over the last few weeks. It seems like a good forum to participate in.

Answer (score 1):

"Compiler dependent code" plays a much smaller role in Ada than in many other languages, such as C or C++. Compiler dependent packages, however, are not uncommon, and compiler-specific pragmas and attributes may be present as well.

Based on my experience, Rational Apex developers seem to have a propensity for excessive (IMHO) use of Rational supplied packages.

One either has to port or reimplement such packages, or recode the Ada that interacts with them to use a pure-Ada approach, which is the highly-preferred option.

Comment: Note that Gnat also comes with a lot of enticing non-standard packages. So he'll need to watch himself as well. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, which I totally hypocritically take full advantage of, justifying it on the grounds that I'm highly unlikely to ever use a different compiler for my personal projects :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, your main difficulty in going between Gnat and another vendor's compiler is going to be dealing with Gnat's oddball file naming requirements. I believe that Rational, like most compilers, will happily use whatever filename you give it, and just keeps track of the mapping with internal files. Gnat is not so forgiving (but doesn't require the internal mapping files).

So if you folks are writing everything from scratch, my reccomendation would be to standardize on Gnat's preferred file naming. This means one source file per Ada program unit, with the file name matching the program unit name, but all lower-case, and dots replaced by hyphens. Package specifications use the `.ads` extension, and program unit bodies use `.adb`.

Otherwise, there isn't much reason why the code can't be completely portable. I worked on one job that had a high-fidelity flight simulator built with a Intermetrics-based front-end for a VxWorks OS target that we were able to rebuild with Gnat at our (Win32) desks for basic desk testing. Even the hard real-time scheduler ported over just fine, as it used all Ada tasking primitives in its implementation. IIRC, the only non-portable calls we had to deal with were a BIOS call to set the TOD clock from its battery backup, and a single VxWorks OS call to set its Real-time Clock frequency. Figuring out how to get everything `gnatchop`ped properly took far more time than stubbing out those two calls.

Comment: By default, Apex uses *.1.ada for specs, and *.2.ada for bodies. Concur with the recommendation, easiest thing is to just script gnatchop to process the set of source files to get them all renamed in a GNAT-happy way.

Comment: @MarcC: If renaming the files is not an option, or is inconvenient, you can just incorporate `gnatchop` into your build procedure.

Comment: @Marc: the Apex naming scheme is one of the simple ones that can be taken care of in [package Naming](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Naming-Schemes.html).

Comment: @SimonWright - True, but that won't handle cases where an Apex user decides for some reason to put multiple program units into a file. You either have to make it very clear to them not to do that (somehow) when their compilers won't, or just officially standardize on the Gnat scheme. As procedures/standards go, I think the latter is more explicit and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. Regarding renaming files I am able to do that using GPS IDE. GPS IDE (uses GNAT compiler) has the option to have either .adb/.ads extension or .1.ada/.2.ada extension. So I could run my project with .1.ada/.2.ada extension also. Don't know what all the other challenges I'm going to face, but file naming constraint is solved.  -- Padmapriya

Answer (score 1):

My current project uses some compiler specific (Branched from `gnat`) features, and we also have a bunch of warnings turned on, which at some point of our compilation, gives us the error message:

```
warning: use of this unit is non-portable and version-dependent
```

If you also ask your compiler to treat warnings as errors, (`-gnatwe`) you should fail compilation when you find them.